# How does verilog behave with negative exponents?

Tags: verilog

How does verilog behave with negative exponents? For example: expression (2**(M-N)) has a negative exponent when both M and N are constant and N is larger than M. What will be issues if I write such code in my RTL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expresson 2<sup>x</sup> gets implemented as an arithmetic shift operation. A negative value of *x* represents a shift left by x.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But please give me little more detail about how 2**x is interpreted as arithmetic shift operation. I think we use <<< or >>> for arithmetic shift operation.

Comment: I was thinking you were taking this expression and multiplying it with another number, or as a fixed point number. But as an integer expression by itself, a negative exponent would result in 0.